# Unable to create index on InnoDB table (5.5.37)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've met with the strange trouble with one InnoDB table.

Index creation on any column fails with error:

```
Incorrect key file for table 'table', try to repair it
```

Despite this error, this table is queryable and there's enough space on disks and RAM.

What reasons can cause this trouble?

**SHOW TABLE STATUS** output:

Name    some_datamart
Engine  InnoDB
Version 10
Row_format  Compact
Rows    364738
Avg_row_length  182
Data_length 66699264
Max_data_length 0
Index_length    0
Data_free   5242880
Auto_increment  null
Update_time null
Check_time  null
Collation   utf8_general_ci
Checksum    null
Create_options  no options

Comment: Can you run `SHOW TABLE STATUS like 'table'` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`table\``? That doesn't look like an InnoDB table to me, but MyISAM corruption.

Comment: @jynus Added status output, and trouble is about **InnoDB** table.

Comment: `C:\Windows\TEMP\#sqlib48.MYI` is a temporary MyISAM Index file, so nothing to do (at least directly) with your real table. It could have been created by a query, though, as temporary tables on disk will be created on MyISAM format on your MySQL version. If InnoDB had corruption, the server would crash directly. Innodb stores indexes either on the common tablespaces or on a .ibd file, so there is not such a thing as a key file for InnoDB.

Comment: @jynus I thought about corruption, however database seems to be alive. Except the fact that I can't create index on a particular table

Comment: Try forcing a full table rebuilt (ALTER TABLE yourtable ENGINE=InnoDB, FORCE), maybe there is something else we are missing.

Comment: @jynus, it worked like a charm!

Comment: @jynus you should post your coimments as an answer.